# How can I create a loop to get the contents of std::map

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdmap

I was need to use associative array, and when heard about STL `std::map` I decided to use it, and I have the following code.

```
map<string, string> aArray;
aArray["First"] = "William";
aArray["Second"] = "James";
aArray["Third"] = "Michael";
aArray["Forth"] = "Jayden";
aArray["Fifth"] = "Ashley";

for(std::map<string, string>::iterator it=aArray.begin();it!=aArray.end();++it){
    cout << it << endl;
}
```

But I don't know how to make a valid loop.
I have seen in other tutorials like the following:

```
cout << it->first << endl;
cout << it->second << endl;
```

But there aren't any members named `first`, `second`.

Also there is an error:

- `no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka
  std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>,
  std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka
  std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>,
  std::basic_string<char> > >}')`

**Please explain to me how can I do that ?**

Comment: Lion for using `It->first` and `It->second you` need to use `pair`

Comment: `there aren't any members named first, second` std::map value_type is a `pair`, and `pair` has `first` and `second`. Do you get an error?

Comment: `map<char*, char*> aArray;` is certainly not what you want for this, the correct type should be `std::map<std::string,std::string> aArray;`

Comment: @triclosan [No](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/250afefbdefb90e3)

Comment: BTW, string literals are `const char *` it is a mistake in C++ to use `char *` for `"string literals"`. 
And for completeness sake: you can use `map< sometype , const char *>` if **all** you are mapping to are **and only are** `"constant string literals"`, but you're better off always using `std::string` in case you change your code later on to use generated strings.
For example `std::map<RGBColor,const char *> color_names; color_names[RGBColor(1, 0, 0)]="Red";` and will **NEVER** use anything but string literals in this map then it'd be fine but it isn't the safest practice. Use std::string.

Comment: Regarding `const char*` to `string`, an inadvertent error when writing the code in my question.

Comment: I'm amazed about some members which voted down to my question. I want to know what is the reason for voting down, what's wrong in my question to correct it ?

Comment: I'm amazed about some members which voted down to my question. you are speedy when voting down, but you are slow when voting up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) A `std::string` is not a `char*` (and a string literal is not a `char*` either), change your map declaration to :

`map<string, string> aArray;`

2) You need to *dereference* the iterator to access the pair :

```
for(std::map<string, string>::iterator it=aArray.begin();it!=aArray.end();++it){
    cout << it->first << endl;
    cout << it->second << endl;
}
```

Or :

```
for(std::map<string, string>::iterator it=aArray.begin();it!=aArray.end();++it){
    cout << (*it).first << endl;
    cout << (*it).second << endl;
}
```

Or much simpler, in c++11 you can just use a for-range loop :

```
for(auto&& pair : aArray){
    cout << pair.first << endl;
    cout << pair.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, regarding the first part of your answer, was an inadvertent error when writing the code. regarding the second part, the second way only works, but the first way does not work, the third way c++11 and I don't want use it. my question here why the first way does not works?

Comment: @LionKing see it working [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69dfa593c443f550) You might have a typo ? Hope this helps.